# when is sign extension done?

Tags: c, msp430

I am compiling C for the MSP430.
I'm wondering what the specific rules are for when sign extension is done for chars (or (u)int8_t) to the register size (16 bit) I found that sign extension will be done when the MSB of the destination operand will affect the correct result of the instruction and all succeeding instructions.
However, this does not really explain it I think. For example when looking at this code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char uscfun ( signed char a, signed char b )
{
    return(a+b)*2;
}

signed char scfun (  char a, signed char b )
{
   return(a+b)*2;
}

signed char scufun ( char a, char b )
{
   return(a+b)<<1;
}

int8_t sint8ufun (  uint8_t a,  int8_t b )
{
   return(a+b)*3;
}

int8_t sint8uufun (  uint8_t a,  uint8_t b )
{
    int8_t new = (a + b)*3;
   //return(a+b)<<1;
   return new;
}

int8_t sint8fun (  int8_t a,  int8_t b )
{
   return(a+b)*2;
}

    
    uint8_t usint8fun (int8_t a, int8_t b)
{
    return((a+b)<<2);
}

uint8_t usint8fun2 (int8_t a, int8_t b)
{
    return(a+b)*4;
}
```

Will give the following assembly (compiled with -O3)

```
    uscfun:
      SXT R12
      SXT R13
      ADD.W R13, R12
      RLA.W R12
      RET
    scfun:
      AND #0xff, R12
      SXT R13
      ADD.W R13, R12
      RLA.W R12
      RET
    scufun:
      AND #0xff, R12
      AND #0xff, R13
      ADD.W R13, R12
      RLA.W R12
      RET
    sint8ufun:
      AND #0xff, R12
      SXT R13
      ADD.W R12, R13
      MOV.B R13, R12
      ADD.B R13, R12
      ADD.B R13, R12
      RET
    sint8uufun:
      ADD.B R13, R12
      MOV.B R12, R13
      ADD.B R12, R13
      ADD.B R13, R12
      RET
    sint8fun:
      SXT R12
      SXT R13
      ADD.W R13, R12
      RLA.W R12
      RET
    usint8fun:
        ADD.B   R13, R12
        rpt     #2 { rlax.w       R12
        RET
usint8fun2:
        SXT     R12
        SXT     R13
        ADD.W   R13, R12
        rpt     #2 { rlax.w       R12
        RET
```

At first I expected that SXT will only be done when the return value of it is signed. However, as the last method shows, this is not necessarily the case. I don't really get why.

Secondly, it seems that bit shifting not always makes for sign extension. Something I would have expected it would since that obviously affects the MSB of the operand. Even better, the last method shows the same instruction twice, just written down different (*2 does the same as <<1), and one needs sign extension and the other does not.

I get that subtraction and adding does not need SXT, but I don't really see when it applies for bit shifting, multiplication and division, and when not.

The question basically is: Is there a set of clear rules when sign extension is used?

EDIT: the example given above, are just examples to show that sign extension are used in a variety of ways, in such ways that I don't really understand what the given rules are about when it is used.

Comment: Any unsigned integer type will never be sign extended.  Signed integer types will be sign extended if they need to be expanded to a larger size.  In the case of `char`, note that whether a bare `char` type is signed or unsigned is implementation-dependent, so if you care, you should explicitly declare it `signed char` or `unsigned char`.  However, `int8_t` is equivalent to `signed char` and `uint8_t` is equivalent to `unsigned char`, so those cases are well-defined.

Comment: The function scufun gets in two unsigned chars (char is standard unsigned for how I use the gcc), they both get zero extended.

Comment: `char` is normally signed in `gcc`, at least for X86 architectures, unless you specify `-funsigned-char`.  In that case, `char` will be unsigned, so in `scufun` both `a` and `b` would be unsigned, so zero-extended rather than sign-extended.  But for the `MSP430` port, perhaps unsigned is the default for `char`.  If you care, then just make it explicit.

Comment: Which is exactly what is happening :) 
Doesn't answer for the bit shifting and multiplication and division though

Comment: You're asking lots of questions at once here, and each test case is varying multiple things at once (try to only vary one thing at a time) and it's not at all clear where you're confused.  Can you give a *specific* case where it's doing something other than what you expect?

Comment: @TomKarzes: OP appears to be asking when sign extension is done in the implemented program (in its machine instructions). Answering in terms of the C model that “Signed integer types will be sign extended if they need to be expanded to a larger size” is not really correct. While `int8_t c = a+b;` converts the `int8_t` `a` and `b` to `int` in the C model, it is readily implemented in assembly with no sign extension.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was answering solely in terms of observable behavior.  There are many optimizations that a compiler can perform that defer or eliminate sign extension, but I see those as compiler optimization questions rather than C questions.  But in any case, there is no single question here.  If OP can pick a function, explain what is expected, and explain how what is seen differs, then it can be answered.  Otherwise it's just a bunch of different test cases, some of which are understood and some of which aren't, and no way to tell the difference.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I know how you were answering, but it is not answering the question OP asked. I am not sure there is not a single question here. It is complicated, but OP is essentially asking when does sign extension actually have to be used to evaluate an expression, versus when it can be ignored. The various functions shown are merely different examples applying to the same question. There may be some single characterization of the answer, perhaps in terms of characteristics of bits of the result in regard to modular arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As a general rule, I would say that it must sign extend when not doing so would produce an incorrect final result.  If the high-order part of the result is discarded, then it may not matter whether an operand is sign-extended or not since the affected bits will not contribute to the final result.  In other cases it's more complicated to analyze.  In the most general case, knowing when it's needed is probably equivalent to the halting problem, i.e. uncomputable.

Comment: the question @EricPostpischil points out is exactly the one I am asking. So it seems that the use of sign extension depends on so many variants that there is no clear way to know when the compiler wil do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let f(*a*, *b*,…) be a function of signed objects *a*, *b*,… Let *a*', *b*',… be the values of those objects reinterpreted as unsigned. If, for all values of *a*, *b*,… (in their signed types), the reinterpretation of f(*a*, *b*,…) as unsigned equals f(*a*', *b*',…), then no sign extension of *a*, *b*,… is needed when evaluating f.

This is evident because, if the condition is satisfied, then f(*a*', *b*',…) produces the bits required to represent f(*a*, *b*,…). However, it may be incomplete. We might have some f(*a*, *b*) that requires a sign extension of *a* but not of *b*, and that is not directly addressed by the above. However, it could be considered included in that f(*a*, *b*) may be expressed as a function g<sub>*a*</sub>(*b*), and then the above tells us no sign extension of *b* is needed when evaluating g<sub>*a*</sub>. If this is true for all g<sub>*a*</sub>, then evaluating f(*a*, *b*) does not require sign extension of *b*.

Also, the fact that a sign extension is not needed does not imply a compiler will necessarily detect this and generate code without sign extension. A compiler might generate sign extension even if it is not necessary. I think this may be seen in `sint8fun`; I would expect `(int8_t) (a+b)*2` to be evaluable as an addition and a shift without sign extension. However, the compiler may be failing to account for the fact that the expression is converted to `int8_t` by the `return`. By itself, `(a+b)*2` does require sign extension, as it could produce a negative `int` result that it would not if the signs were not extended. It is only after the conversion to `int8_t` that the result is then independent of sign extension.

Comment: It is that very function which is throwing me off.

Comment: I have found another example, which seems to indeed indicate that it is the fault of the compiler. Examples are in the original post on the bottom of the two code snippets. They both do the exact same thing, even in assembly. But one gets sign extended and the other one does not

Answer (score 1):

> The question basically is: Is there a set of clear rules when sign extension is used?

**TL;DR**: inasmuch as you seem to be talking about sign-extension machine instructions, the answer is a flat "no".

Sign extension is not a C concept, so the language specifies no rules about when it is performed.  C does have rules about the circumstances under which values are *converted* to wider types, and for most C implementations, some of those conversions would, in principle, involve sign extension, but that's not the same thing.  It's especially not the same thing because for the most part, implementations are allowed to do what they want with your code as long as they manifest the externally-observable behavior that follows from it, as defined by the language standard.

The language specifies that expressions of type `signed char` and (`signed`) `short` are converted to (`signed`) `int` wherever they appear as operands of arithmetic operators, bitwise operators, logical operators, and the indexing operator, as part of the "integer promotions".  `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` are converted to (`signed`) `int` under the same circumstances if `int` can represent all values of those types, or to `unsigned int` under those circumstances otherwise.  I may may have overlooked a few other cases.
Plain `char` will behave either like `signed char` in all respects or like `unsigned char` in all respects, depending on C implementation.

Those implicit conversions are undoubtedly the unifying factor behind your observations about trends in your compiler's generation of `SXT` instructions.  A compiler may emit such instructions to implement the required conversions, but it is not obligated to do so where it can achieve the same result without.